# What would be the natural answer on "I am sorry"?

Tags: sentence-usage

What would be the answer for someone who asks "**Sorry**"?
For example, If someone insulted or hurt me, and then asks "**Sorry**" or says "**I am sorry, please**".

If I want to tell him that I accept it (or alternatively if I want to refuse it), then what is the typical way to do that? How about "I forgive you" or "I don't forgive you", does it work here?

Answer (score 6):

***I forgive you*** would be for something sincere and serious, like a hurtful insult or even serious crimes.

For something formal or written, you can say ***I accept your apology.***

A very common phrase, as @CookieMonster mentions, is ***It's OK*** or ***It's all right***.

Sometimes, people apologize out of politeness, just in case the other person might be offended. In such a situation, people often respond with ***No worries*** or ***No problem.*** For example, if you texted your friend that you were running ten minutes late to meet her, hopefully she would say, "No worries!"

Another very common phrase is ***No need to apologize***.

There are other more colorful expressions, such as:

> ***Don't worry about it.***
>
> ***Forget about it!***
>
> ***Don't even stress!***
>
> ***Don't even trip!***

If you *don't* forgive someone, you can usually add "not" or "don't" to the phrases above:

> ***I don't forgive you.***
>
> ***It's not OK.***
>
> ***That's not good enough!***
>
> ***Talk to the hand!***

Comment: "it's all right" is not the correct spelling, as far as I know.

Comment: I don't think "alright" is a real word, at least not in the U.S.

Comment: I always thought that "alright" is an adjective that means "fine". "all right" literally means "100% correct" or "each one in a group is correct".

Comment: "Alright" is a variant spelling of "all right", in all of the uses of that expression.  It's less formal (and some would argue incorrect), but it's commonplace and growing in usage, although still less common than "all right".

Comment: Seems like everything I learned as a student is just being thrown out the window. :-( The rule I learned was that it's "all right" and definitely NOT "alright" -- that just because a lot of people misspell it doesn't make it OK to misspell it. Now that sounds old-fashioned, but it makes a lot of sense to me on a certain level.

Comment: Well, English is a living language, and what spellings are acceptable changes with time.  A whole lot of beloved English words arose as misspellings or variant spellings of other words and phrases.  That said, if I were writing formally, I'd definitely use "all right", but I might pop off a quick "alright" even in casual business correspondence.

Comment: @PMV - Yes, I understand this. I just don't like it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Canada, it's acceptable to respond back to **"Sorry"** with **"Sorry,"** especially if one person has bumped into the other person on the street or something like that.  This is distinctly Canadian though and other English speakers sometimes make fun of Canadians for overusing the word **sorry**.

Answer (score 1):

> It's alright.
>
> It's okay.
>
> No need to apologize.